# Google recaptcha validation using jquery validate plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validate plugin. I have used 2 google recaptcha in single page. So the code is bit different from what we normally see. I was validating if the response is empty or checked. But I am getting blank response every time(even if I check the captcha).

Html -

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" id="recaptcha1"></div>
<div class="g-recaptcha" id="recaptcha2"></div>
```

JS -

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=myCallBack&render=explicit" async defer></script>
<script>
    var recaptcha1;
    var recaptcha2;
    var myCallBack = function() {
        //Render the recaptcha1 on the element with ID "recaptcha1"
        recaptcha1 = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha1', {
            'sitekey' : '6Ld28cISAAAAACLXX5xgaV1nemEoTw5uxnGhsyVc', //Replace this with your Site key
            'theme' : 'dark'
        });

        //Render the recaptcha2 on the element with ID "recaptcha2"
        recaptcha2 = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha2', {
            'sitekey' : '6Ld28cISAAAAACLXX5xgaV1nemEoTw5uxnGhsyVc', //Replace this with your Site key
            'theme' : 'dark'
        });
    };
</script>
```

Jquery validate plugin

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("form[name='contactform']").validate({
            rules: {
                yname: {
                    required: true,
                    lettersonly: true
                },
            ...................
            rest of the code
            ......................
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                //form.submit();
                alert(grecaptcha.getResponse());
                if (grecaptcha.getResponse()) {
                    form.submit();
                } else {
                    alert('Please confirm captcha to proceed')
                }
            }
         }
            });
```

Do I need to check the response outside document ready? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Don't you have to validate google's `reCaptcha` server side? I though client side is impossible to validate, because you have to send the code to the google's server, which is impossible using `ajax`.

Comment: @RichardMauritz Right. I have not thought about that. Then I have to use ajax and get the response.. I will try with it now. Thanks

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra `getResponse(widgetId)` should return you a valid key, this key you validate on your backend. Are you using `invisible` grecaptcha?

Comment: @loelsonk I am using reCaptcha v2. What is widgetId